# How to add an if condition in my d3js example

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, d3.js

consider the jsfiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/5D5eD/5/. It has data values [2,2],[3,3],[4,4],  [5, 4],[5.5, 5],[6, 6],[6, 7],[5,6]. Here in this example the last two values are [6,7] and [5,6]. I want to add a condition i.e if y value is lesser than previous value then the datapoint should increment the y value by 1 unit. In my case the line from [6,7] to [5,6] should be replaced by a line from [6,7] to [5,8]. How to achieve this in the code ?

```
 var line = d3.svg.line()
 .x(function(d){return x(d[0]);})
  .y(function(d){return y(d[1]);})
 .interpolate("linear");  

   g.append("path")
  .attr("d", function(d) { return line(data)})
  .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)")
   .style("stroke-width", 2)
        .style("stroke", "steelblue")
        .style("fill", "none");
   // end of drawing lines

       main.append("g")
   .attr("class", "grid")
   .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
   .call(make_x_axis()
   .tickSize(-height, 0, 0)
   .tickFormat(""))

    main.append("g")
   .attr("class", "grid")
   .call(make_y_axis()
   .tickSize(-width, 0, 0)
   .tickFormat(""))

    function make_x_axis() {
    return d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom")
     .ticks(30)
     }

    function make_y_axis() {
    return d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .ticks(17)
    }
```

Comment: point 8 is not present in graph. Do you want point to be [5, 7] ?

Comment: ya point 8 is not present, can it increment as (Yprevious + 1). Yes it will be helpful if I can get [5,7].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5D5eD/9/). I think this is what you want.

```
var py;
data.map(
    function(d) {
        if (d[1] < py)
            d[1] = py + 1;
        py = d[1];
    }
);
```

Comment: Thanks FernOfTheAndes, Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't know more efficient method than this but it met your requirement.

Use condition in returning `y` axis values in both drawing circle and lines using :

`(i>0 && d[1]<data[i-1][1]) ? y(data[i-1][1]) : y(d[1]); (where i is index from function(d, i) { ... })`

**Two lines changed in following:**

```
// Drawing circles
g.selectAll("scatter-dots")
.data(data)
    .enter().append("svg:circle")
    .attr("cx", function (d, i) {  return x(d[0]); }) 
    .attr("cy", function (d, i) { return (i>0 && d[1]<data[i-1][1]) ? y(data[i-1][1]) : y(d[1]); }) 
    .attr("r", 5)
    .style("fill", function (d) { return color(d[0]);}) ;

// begin of drawing lines
var line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d){return x(d[0]);})
.y(function(d, i){ return (i>0 && d[1]<data[i-1][1]) ? y(data[i-1][1]) : y(d[1]); })
    .interpolate("linear");
```

**[Updated Fiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/budhram/5D5eD/6/)**

Comment: ram it does that for only one value, if I add one more datapoint as [4,5] it repeats the old pattern.

Comment: what is expected after adding [4, 5] to [6, 7],[5,6] and old pattern means? [6, 7], [5, 7], [4, 7] ?

Comment: I want this pattern http://jsfiddle.net/5D5eD/7/ after adding [6,7],[5,6] and [4,5]

Comment: and I guess and adding any datapoint y axis should increase by 1?

Comment: yes but only when Ypresent value < Yprevious value [only when the present value is less than previous value]